# Can't reach home network from outside

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

As the title states I’m trying to reach my home network from outside, my goal is to be able to connect to a VPN server on said home network.

Ior starters, I have a TP-Link Archer MR600 LTE+ router with matching 4G unlimited traffic SIM by Vodafone. I'll describe the steps I’ve followed :

1. I’ve started by setting up DDNS on my router through TP-Link’s DDNS service, as my IP is dynamic.
2. Yes, the IP should be public as it always results as a class A IP address, also the IP I can see assigned to my WAN interface on the router matches what “What’s my IP address" services report, the DDNS domain also resolves to the same matching IP address.
3. I’ve setup an OpenVPN server directly on my router, as it has that capability, to no avail, a TLS handshake can’t be established from outside network.
4. I have then tried to setup an AlgoVPN server on a local Ubuntu Server bridged network VM, to whom I reserved a static IP by MAC from router DHCP and forwarded (or better tried to) the ports needed. No handshake can be established.
5. I have monitored traffic for both VPN Servers with Wireshark, when trying from outside network I couldn’t really tell any difference from when the servers sit idle, some ICMP or ARP requests here and there.
6. I have then tried to test port forwarding by setting up a port listener in TCP protocol on my pc, forward and allow on Windows firewall the corresponding ports and telnet to them from outside, no positive responses.
7. Then I’ve tried to execute tracert, I saw the route reach some sort of Vodafone's relay by 10th hop, after the 12th hop requests started to timeout, to no final response, my public IP couldn't be reached apparently.
8. I've also allowed ICMP requests from outside and disabled completely the IPv4 firewall on my router, no change to all of the points above.

I’m really puzzled, all normal traffic, games, streaming, browsing work perfectly (and I can reach both VPN servers from LAN, so at least i know those work), I’ve even tried to setup everything using common ports like 80 for the Wireguard Algo uses and 443 for SSH.

I’m hypothesizing that there could be some sort of firewall by my ISP’s side that to allow traffic through requires my IP to make the requests first, which I don’t know how would work based on my limited networking knowledge. On Server Fault someone said that they could be blocking server type traffic.

If anyone has any cloues as to why this may be happening, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: I have executed the tracert to some public IPs like @Albin suggested, my router does indeed result as the first hop
As to what @Mark Scheck suggested here’s a screenshot (below) of the port forwarding and nmap scan results. Nmap scan was executed on my DDNS domain from inside the LAN. I’ll have to try and check out nmap better in the weekend.

[image]

**EDIT 2**: I have noticed something strange, my is has a hostname already associated with the ip, as the following screenshot. My DDNS domain resolves to the same ip, but could this be indicative of CGNAT or some other kind of block from the ISP? I still have to contact them

[image]

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the open ports on the router/firewall of the openvpn server. Use nmap to verify they are actually listening.

Comment: Later this evening when i get home i'll do that

Comment: Vodaphone usually uses carrier-grade NAT on their mobile plans, this doesn't seem to be your case though but just to make sure, please traceroute a public IP (e.g. 8.8.8.8) and check for the first entries. The first one should be your router's LAN-IP, what is the second one?

Comment: i have added an edit taking in consideration your points @MarkScheck and Albin

Comment: Please post the result of the trace, the first hop is NOT the relevant info. Other then that, can you ping the router? From your LAN? Form the "outside"?

Comment: I would concentrate on the router/routerVPN for now but further information (hardware/connections and logical/IPs/ports) about your network/devices (router, server, PC and anything in between) might be helpful as well for troubleshooting the issues on the Linux server and PC.

Comment: @Albin i'm sorry i've misinterpreted your first question, i'll post the screenshots again later tonight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115158/discussion-between-laxfar-and-albin).

Comment: “I’m hypothesizing that there could be some sort of firewall by my ISP’s side” - This is very likely given the fact we are talking about a 4G network.